# showing as sublist of muliselect customers contacts on customer record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have Multi select field(sourced with customers) on customer record, i have to show the contacts of the selected customers on multi select field as a sublist, please help me

Comment: who voted this to degrade, do you understood what i asked

Answer (score 0):

First create the Multi-select Customer List..[ i think you did that as far as my understanding from you question]..

Second you have to trigger the Field Change Client Script on "Customer" multiselect field which will run the Search on Contacts...

In criteria search for company with customer's IDs you'll get the Search Sublist of Contacts...just show it UP...